# How can I improve my code for drawing a tree?

Tags: programming, functional-style

This code draws a tree, but it's not in the functional style.

```
tree[set_, m_] := 
  Module[{θ, mz, my, temp, k, i, p1, p2, a, b, c, d, e, f},
   θ = Pi/6;
   mz = {{Cos[θ], -Sin[θ]}, {Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}}; 
   my = {{Cos[-θ], -Sin[-θ]}, {Sin[-θ], Cos[-θ]}};
   temp = set;
   p1 = {};(*store branch*)
   p2 = {};(*store leaf*)
   For[k = 1, k <= m, k++, p2 = {};
    For[i = 1, i <= Length[temp], i++, a = temp[[i, 2]];
     b = temp[[i, 1]];
     c = 1/3*a + 2/3*b;
     d = c + mz.(a - b)*(1/3);
     e = c + my.(a - b)*(1/3);
     AppendTo[p1, {Brown, Thickness[0.035/k], Line[{b, c}]}];
     AppendTo[p2, {c, a}];
     AppendTo[p2, {c, d}];
     AppendTo[p2, {c, e}];
     ];
    temp = p2;
    ];

   Show[Graphics[{p1, {RGBColor[0.1, 0.42, 0.17], Line[p2]}}, 
     Axes -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 0.2}, {-0.2, 1.}}]]];

tree[{{{0., 0.}, {0., 1.}}}, 7]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A friend of mine tried rewrite it with `Nest`, but it worked slower than the original code.

```
(leaf = Nest[Apply[Transpose[{Table[(2 #1 + #2)/3, {3}], 
           {RotationTransform[-5 Pi/6, (2 #1 + #2)/3][#1], 
          RotationTransform[
            5 Pi/6, (2 #1 + #2)/3][#1], #2}}] &, #, {-3}] &, 
            {{{0, 0.}, {0, 1}}}, 7]; 
  Graphics[Map[{RGBColor[0.1, 0.42, 0.17], Line[#]} &, leaf, {-3}]]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think `Nest` is slower than loops. How do I rewrite it to make it faster?

If possible, use `Fold`, `Nest` or similar functional constructs.

Comment: And you forgot to mention that I only managed to reproduce the leaves. (I really don't know where to store the thick and thin branches ORZ…)

Comment: You might be interested in my two cents' worth which I posted [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#Pitfalls). That page has a link to the [Tree Bender](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TreeBender/) demonstration, too.

Comment: Perhaps of interest, from the [2012 oneliner contest](www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/mathematica-experts-live-one-liner-competition-2012/): http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=282&video=1291

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's my approach. I've put the core of the algorithm into a function `iterate` which takes a `leaf` and returns a `branch` and 3 leaves. Each leaf or branch is defined by a start point, an end point, and your `k` variable which is used to set the `Thickness`.

The tree is constructed by `Nest`ing the `iterate` function 7 times, starting with an initial `leaf` expression.

Finally I use `Cases` to extract the branches and leaves and convert them to graphics primitives.

```
θ = Pi/6;
mz = {{Cos[θ], -Sin[θ]}, {Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}};
my = {{Cos[-θ], -Sin[-θ]}, {Sin[-θ], Cos[-θ]}};

iterate[leaf[{b_, a_, k_}]] := Module[{c, d, e},
  c = 1/3*a + 2/3*b;
  d = c + mz.(a - b)*(1/3);
  e = c + my.(a - b)*(1/3);
  {branch[{b, c, k + 1}], leaf[{c, a, k + 1}], leaf[{c, d, k + 1}], leaf[{c, e, k + 1}]}]

iterate[b_branch] := b

tree = Nest[Flatten[iterate /@ #] &, {leaf[{{0., 0.}, {0., 1.}, 0}]}, 7];

Graphics[{
  Brown,
  Cases[tree, branch[{x_, y_, k_}] :> {Thickness[0.035/k], Line[{x, y}]}],
  RGBColor[0.1, 0.42, 0.17], 
  Cases[tree, leaf[{x_, y_, k_}] :> Line[{{x, y}}]]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Works nicely with 12 instead of 7 and takes 1/2 minute; of course the obvious next question is .. what about a 3D tree? :-)

Answer (score 10):

There are now a couple of answers that show how to generate your tree in a very functional way.  Really, though, your approach is not too bad so it might be worth seeing how to make *minimal* changes to your algorithm and speed up the result.

In terms of speed, the most serious problem with your code is the repeated use of `AppendTo`.  The reason is that lists are implemented internally as arrays so the  `Append` and `AppendTo` commands require that the entire list be moved in memory.  This is very slow, particularly when building potentially long lists of arbitrary length.  Here's a simple example:

```
list = {};
Do[AppendTo[list, k], {k, 1, 100000}] // Timing

(* Out: {29.5157, Null} *)
```

If you need to build a list of arbitrary length, you have several alternatives; pre-allocation and use of `Sow`/`Reap` are commonly mentioned in this context. Another undocumented but oft mentioned tool is the `Bag` buried in the `Internal` context.  You can reimplement the above using a `Bag` like so:

```
bag = Internal`Bag[];
Do[Internal`StuffBag[bag, k], {k, 1, 100000}] // Timing

(* Out: {0.044028, Null} *)
```

It's so much faster since the internal representation is completely different - a linked list, as opposed to an array I suppose.  If we're going to use the `Bag` commands a lot, we can add the `Internal` context to our `$ContextPath`.

```
If[! MemberQ[$ContextPath, "Internal`"],
    AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Internal`"]];
```

Now, here's a rewrite of your algorithm using `Bag`s in place of `List`s.  There are a couple of other small differences as well; I've replaced the `For` loops with `Do` loops, for example, but the performance change is primarily due to the `Bag`/`List` difference.

```
tree2[theta_, depth_,initialDirection_:{{{0., 0.}, {0., 1.}}}] := 
  Module[{rotateLeft, rotateRight, k, i, temp, p1, p2, a, b, c, d, e},
   rotateLeft = RotationMatrix[theta];
   rotateRight = RotationMatrix[-theta];
   temp = Bag[{{{0., 0.}, {0., 1.}}}];
   p1 = Bag[];(*store branch*)
   Do[
     p2 = Bag[];(*store leaf*)
     Do[
       {b,a} = BagPart[temp,i];
       c = a/3+2b/3;
       d = c + rotateLeft.(a-b)/3;
       e = c + rotateRight.(a-b)/3;
       StuffBag[p1, {Brown, Thickness[0.035/k], Line[{b, c}]}];
       StuffBag[p2, {c,a}];
       StuffBag[p2, {c,d}];
       StuffBag[p2, {c,e}],
       {i, 1, BagLength[temp]}];
     temp = p2,
    {k, 1, depth}];
    Graphics[{BagPart[p1,All], 
     {RGBColor[0.1, 0.42, 0.17], Line[BagPart[p2,All]]}}, 
     Axes -> 1, PlotRange->{{-0.2,0.2},{-0.2,1.}}]
];
```

Let's try it at depth 9 while supressing the output so that we time just the computation.

```
treePic2 = tree2[Pi/6, 8]; // Timing

(* Out: {0.167719, Null} *)
```

Here's the same computation for your `tree` command.

```
treePic = tree[{{{0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0}}}, 8]; // Timing

(* Out: {7.135478, Null} *)
```

At depth 10, the `Bag` version takes about 1.5 seconds; I aborted the `List` version.  You can see the images by just executing the name:

```
treePic2

(* Out: Same pic!!! *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Your tree can be described using a parametric L-system, as described in Prusinkiewicz and Lindenmayer's classic The Algorithmic Beauty of Plants.  Here is a very short description of a Mathematica implementation.  A more complete description can be found in [this paper](http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/papers/PLSystemsPP.pdf); largely, this is an extension of the ideas in Chapter 8 of Stan Wagon's *Mathematica in Action*.  As the paper was written with V5, it could certainly be updated, but here are the basics.

In the language of L-systems, the basic structure your tree can be described something like so:

```
subs = F[s_, w_] (* initial configuration, one step forward *) :> {
  F[0.6 s, 0.7 w] (* Forward, not as far and not as thick *),
  push (* store current state *),
  r[Pi/6] (* Rotate left *),
  F[0.2 s, 0.7 w] (* Another step forward *),
  pop  (* Recall last position stored *),
  (* Then more of the same *)
  push, F[0.4 s, 0.7 w], pop, push, r[-Pi/6], 
  F[0.2 s, 0.7 w], pop, 
  setWidth[w]
};
```

Now, we iterate this replacement rule starting from a single step forward and take a look at a small portion of the result.  (Fundamentally, this is where the iteration occurs.)

```
instructions = Flatten[Nest[# /. subs &, {setWidth[0.035], F[1, 0.035]}, 7]];
instructions[[10 ;; 30]]

(* Out: {push, r[-Pi/6], F[0.4, 0.00288], pop, setWidth[0.00411], push, r[Pi/6],
 F[0.4, 0.00288], push, r[Pi/6], F[0.16, 0.00288], pop, push, F[0.28,0.00288], 
 pop, push, r[-Pi/6], F[0.16, 0.00288], pop, setWidth[0.00411], pop} *)
```

Next, we need to interpret these instructions as a list of grapics primitives.

```
theta = Pi/6;
thePath = {};
lastpt = {0,0};
dir = {0,1};
currentWidth = 0.04;
stack = N[{lastpt, dir, currentWidth}];
instructions /. {
  (* Movement *)
  F[x_, t___] :> 
    (thePath = {thePath, {currentWidth, {lastpt, lastpt += x*dir}}};),
  (* Rotation *)
  r[t_] :> (dir = RotationMatrix[t].dir;),
  (* Branching structures *)
  push :> (stack = Flatten[{{{lastpt, dir,
       rotleft, rotright, currentWidth, currentColor}}, 
       stack}, 1];),
  pop :> (dir = stack[[1, 2]]; lastpt = stack[[1, 1]]; 
      rotleft = stack[[1, 3]]; rotright = stack[[1, 4]]; 
      currentWidth = stack[[1,5]]; currentColor = stack[[1,6]];
      stack = Rest[stack];),
  (* Changing width *)
  setWidth[t_] :> (currentWidth = t)
};
pathData = Partition[Flatten[thePath],5];
widths = Thickness /@ (First /@ pathData);
lines = Line /@ (Partition[#,2]& /@ (Rest /@ pathData));
lines = Transpose[{widths, lines}] /. Thickness[t_] :> If[t<0.005,
  Unevaluated[Sequence[Thickness[t],Darker[Green]]],
  Unevaluated[Sequence[Thickness[t],Darker[Brown]]]
];
```

Finally, we display.

```
Graphics[lines]
```

[image]