# How to create a fractal tree?

Tags: graphics, programming, fractals

I want to create a fractal tree, using translation and rotation. Code below is working for one level, but when I try loop, it is not giving output. Code is given below:

```
        threshold = 4;
        L = 100;
        While[
          L > threshold,
          line = Line[{{0, 0}, {0, -L}}];
          Graphics[
             {line, 
              Scale[#, 
                 2/3, {0, 
                  0}] & /@ (Rotate[
                   Translate[line, {0, L}], # Degree, {0, 0}] & /@ {-30, 
                  30})}] 
            L = L*0.67;
          ];
```

Comment: Related: [154213](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154213).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[next];

next[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] =
  (
     {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} //
        TranslationTransform[{x2 - x1, y2 - y1}] //
       RotationTransform[# Pi/6, {x2, y2}] //
      ScalingTransform[2/3 {1, 1}, {x2, y2}]
     ) & /@ {-1, 1};

list = NestList[Join @@ next /@ # &, N@{{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}}, 5];

Graphics[Line /@ list]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, Thank you so very much @chyang.

Comment: @BiSarfraz You are welcome.

Answer (score 8):

> I am not only new in Mathematica, but also new in Maths. I need a very simple approach

*(This answer attempts to be a "reference answer" with relevant links.)*

This has been discussed extensively in MSE and Mathematica blogs and demonstrations.

- MSE:

  - [How can I improve my code for drawing a tree?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16825/34008)
  - [L-System in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143214/l-system-in-mathematica)
- Mathematica Journal:

  - [A New Method of
    Constructing Fractals and
    Other Graphics](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/data/uploads/2011/02/Helmstedt.pdf)
- Demonstrations:

  - [Fractal Trees](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FractalTrees/)
  - [Radial FractalTree](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RadialFractalTree/)
  - [FibonacciTree](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FibonacciTree/)
- Blogs:

  - [Adventures into the Mathematical Forest of Fractal Trees](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/05/22/adventures-into-the-mathematical-forest-of-fractal-trees/).
  - [Fractals at 4am](https://antonantonov.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/fractals-at-4am/)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @BiSarfraz You are welcome, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with your code is that it's lacking a way to combine the different levels of the tree. `Graphics` are not automatically printed, unless they are the final result of a computation.

The following code should get you started:

```
tree[L_, th_] /; L > th := With[
  {line = Line[{{0, 0}, {0, -L}}]},
  {
   line,
   Scale[#, 2/3, {0, 0}] & /@ (Rotate[Translate[tree[0.67 L, th], {0, L}], # Degree, {0, 0}] & /@ {-30, 30})}
  ]
tree[__] := {}


tree[100, 10] // Graphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The key ingredients are:

- Recursion of the `tree` function to combine the different parts. The termination condition is implemented using [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (`/;`)
- `Rotate`,`Scale`,`Transform` can be arbitrarily nested, allowing for a clean specification of the nested levels

As you can see, the result is not correct yet (the lines are too short), but you should be able to easily fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much for making things easy.

Comment: I have fixed it: line,
   Scale[#, 2/3, {0, 0}] & /@ (Rotate[Translate[tree[0.67 L, th], {0, 0.67L}], # Degree, {0, 0}] & /@ {-30, 30})}
  ]